# Free Download of Datatable css

Tags: css, datatable, themes

I would like to change the css feel of my datatable. I am currently using jquerydatatables.css and jquery-ui.css. Is there any free download of datatable css?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking the datatables website?

https://datatables.net/manual/styling/theme-creator

They provide support for several themes.

> This online style builder will let you customise the colouring of the DataTables stylesheet to fit in seamlessly with your web-site or app. Simply select the colours you want for your table using the options below, and click the Create stylesheet button. The page will then reload and show your customised table below, with the CSS available to copy and paste for your site.

Comment: The link provides ThemeRoller styling for components such as accordion, datepicker etc. I want styling only for the table. Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct link-
[Data tables applying your own css](http://datatables.net/manual/styling/theme-creator) for changing the css of datatables.

1. You can provide it your own theme.
2. Just select the colors and
       styling.
3. It will generate a CSS for your applied styling.
4. You can copy
               in your css file.
5. You are good to go.

Hope this helps...